# Using scanf for particular inputs

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char z[10];
    scanf("%[aeiou]",z);
    printf("%s",z);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to enter a string and want the output which includes a,e,i,o,u only as specified in `scanf` function. I want to try getting the output using only `scanf`.

Comment: Your code [works for me](https://ideone.com/H1rw5h). What's your issue?

Comment: If you are trying to read a string containing various characters and printed only the vowels from it, then `scanf` with `"%[aeiou]"` is not what you want. That tells `scanf` to read only a, e, i, o, and u, and to stop when it sees anything else. You would want to continue to read the whole string. So, if this is what you want, you should read the entire string, then print only the vowels. (You can read the entire string character-by-character; you do not need to read it all at once.)

Comment: You are right. I was trying to read only the vowels and then print that, but I wasn’t sure on how to do that.

Comment: It *is* possible to do this with scanf and loop, but you'd really want to process the input yourself character by character and check if each of them is a vowel or not.

Answer (score 1):

1) Avoid a width-less string format such as `"%[aeiou]"` - it is prone to overflow.

2) Check `scanf()` return value.

To avoid limitations such as 10, read input in a loop.

```
int main(void) {
    char z[10];
    while (scanf("%9[aeiou]",z) == 1) {
      printf("%s",z);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

If code needs to read input like `xxxaxxxaxxx` and output `aa` only with `scanf()`, more work is needed.

To be clear `scanf()` is not the best tool to use to accomplish this goal.

Some untested idea of what is needed.

```
int main(void) {
  do {
    int cnt; 
    char z[10];
    while ((cnt = scanf("%9[aeiou]",z)) == 1) {
      printf("%s",z);
    }
    if (cnt == EOF) {
      break;
    }

    // Find the character that stopped scanning
    if ((cnt = scanf("%1[^aeiou]",z)) == 1) {
      if (z[0] == '\n') {
        break;
      }
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```